# I want to to change the setTimeout value when there is data change

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

For now, I'm building a Queue System, I have the ajax function like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
(function worker() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/queue/queue_list.php', 
    success: function(data) {
      $('#result').html(data);
    },
    complete: function() {
      // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
     setTimeout(worker, 3000);
    }
  });
})();
<script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

In the function, system will refresh the data every 3 seconds to update the table view if there is data changes.

What I want is, when there is data change on queue_list.php, setTimeout will change to 20 seconds (to play voice call), but if no data change, the setTimeout value will no change.
How can Ii change the setTimeout value?

queue_list.php

```
<?php
function nomornya($loket,$huruf){
include"database.php";
    $sqlnyah="select count(id) as ceknya from panggilan_antrian where loket='$loket' and huruf='$huruf'";
    $sqlnyah2="select nomor from panggilan_antrian where loket='$loket' and huruf='$huruf'";
    $querynyah=mysqli_query($sqlnyah);
    $angkan=mysqli_fetch_assoc($querynyah);
    $angkany=$angkan[ceknya];
    if($angkany!=0){
        $querynyah2=mysqli_query($sqlnyah2);
        $angkan2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($querynyah2);
        $angkanya=$angkan2[nomor];
    }else{
        $angkanya="0";
    }
    echo $angkanya;

}
?>
<style>
table,tr,td{
    font-size:1.7em;
}
</style>
<table style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
    <tr style="background:#000000; color:#ffffff;">
        <td>COUNTER</td>
        <td>NOMOR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background:#b1c2f3">
        <td>1</td>
        <td><?php nomornya(1,null); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background:#d2f3b1">
        <td>2A</td>
        <td><?php nomornya(2,A); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background:#b1c2f3">
        <td>2B</td>
        <td><?php nomornya(2,B); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background:#d2f3b1">
        <td>2C</td>
        <td><?php nomornya(2,C); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background:#b1c2f3">
        <td>3</td>
        <td><?php nomornya(3,null); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background:#d2f3b1">
        <td>4</td>
        <td><?php nomornya(4,null); ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can declare the timeout as a variable and clear it.

```
setTimeout(worker, 3000);
```

would become

```
var workerTimeout = setTimeout(worker, 3000);
```

when you need to clear it you

```
ClearTimeout (workerTimeout);
```

and then set it again to new value.

```
workerTimeout = setTimeout (worker, 20000);
```

Comment: i don't know how to use it, how can i check if data updated and then set new timeout?

Answer (score 0):

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) returns timeoutID, you can use this ID to cancel already set timeout.

But I would not suggest you to use timeouts here, try setInterval. 
Here is how it might look

```
var updateBlocked = false;
function worker() {
    if (updateBlocked) return;
    // your code to fetch new info
}

setInterval(worker, 3000);

function onSomeEvent() {
    updateBlocked = true;
    setTimeout(function(){updateBlocked = false;}, 20000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple as this: assign the timeout value to a variable and change the timeout variable whenever needed. Something like this:

```
(function worker() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/queue/queue_list.php', 
    success: function(data) {
      $('#result').html(data);
    },
    complete: function() {
      var timeout = 3000;
      //change in data, since timeout was already set on previous data change. Hence, update timeout value too and clear previous timeout
      if(typeof timer!='undefined') {
       clearTimeout(timer);
       timeout = 20*1000;
      }
      // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
     var timer = setTimeout(worker, timeout);
    }
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

**setTimeout** is a native JavaScript function, which calls a function or executes a code after a specified delay(millisecond)

```
setTimeout(function(){

worker() // call your function here


},3000);
```